# Binary representation of the inverse of a big number

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, key-generation

In one of the first FHE schemes by Gentry, the KeyGen algorithm is defined as follow:

For a security parameter $\lambda$, set $N = \lambda ^ 2, P = \lambda ^ 2, Q = \lambda ^ 5$.

*KeyGen*$(\lambda)$: Generate a random $P$-bit odd integer, $p$. A set $\vec{y} = \{ y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_\beta\}$ is generated with $y_i$ bits. There must exist a sparse subset $S \subset \vec{y}$ of $\alpha$ elements such that $\sum\limits_{y_j \in S} (y_j) = \frac{1}{p} \mod 2$.

Set $sk$ to be a binary encoding of the subset $S$, where $s = (0,1)^\beta$.
Set $pk \leftarrow (p, \vec{y})$.

My problem here is with the subset S. Especially, for a large enough security parameter, the random integer $p$ is so large that I don't see how to print its inverse on my terminal. Are there some specific libraries in Python or C to handle this kind of inverse? I have tried to shift it by the size of p in base 10 but the problem remains as I can't convert p to float/double before dividing.

This may not be the most accurate forum for this question, and I apologize in advance if it is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In RSA, how does the CPU deal with this huge modulus (8192 bits)?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35586/in-rsa-how-does-the-cpu-deal-with-this-huge-modulus-8192-bits)

Comment: Hmmm indeed these two questions are kinda similar but in my opinion I don't think we can consider them as duplicate, especially by considering the answers of this other RSA topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first $k$ digits on the right of the decimal point of the representation of $1/p$ in base $b$ also are the representation in base $b$ of $\left\lfloor b^k/p\right\rfloor$ left-padded to $k$ digits with zeroes.

If we want to perform computations to $k$ places after the decimal point for quantity $x\in\Bbb R$, we can use the integer quantity $\left\lfloor b^k\,x\right\rfloor$, or better $\left\lfloor b^k\,x+\frac12\right\rfloor$.

Any language (e.g. [python](https://www.python.org/)) or library (e.g. [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)) capable of handling arbitrary precision integers let you make the necessary computations.

E.g. in python 3,

```
p = 3**161
print("{0:b}".format(2**700//p))
```

yields a 445-bit bitstring which, padded with 255 `0` on the left, and then `0.` on the left, is $1/p$ in binary to 700 binary places.

Comment: hmmm your example actually works but for my case with larger p (especially the example above of 16k bits) I simply get 0... And this size in bits can be potentially bigger than 16k

(I tried both on my IDE and in a terminal with different versions of python 3)

Comment: Oh sorry I think I understood my mystake, I was keeping 2**700 for my bigger p but of course I need to update it... Thanks for your help!